# Can I send a UDP datagram from my android device to a server on my PC. Android device connected over USB

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, datagram

I am building an android application that needs to send data in realtime to a server on my PC. The UDP server is in C# and it is already able to receive data from another client on my PC, just not from my android device.

In my android app I was able to set up a TCP client and was able to connect and send data to a TCP server on my PC, but the TCP connection was not fast enough for the amount of data I am needing to send so I need to use UDP. I am also able to make calls to a REST server running on my PC.

The android device is connected to the same wifi network as my PC and is also connected over USB.
I have seen similar code snippets to mine work using the android device emulator rather than a physical device but I am having no luck with the emulator either.

I have been messing around with DatagramSockets and Packets in android, here is what I have so far:

This is the class I am using to send the Datagram. For the InetAddress, I have tried the ip address of my PC as well as local host with no luck. Both the TCP connection and the REST api worked fine using localhost as the address and port forwarding but this is not working with UDP.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;


public class UDPTestClient extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... strings) {
        try {
            // Create Socket and set broadcast to true
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            socket.setBroadcast(true);
            // I have also tried the IP address of my pc in place of localhost
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            String messageStr = "hello world";
            byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();
            // Create DatagramPacket
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, addr, 5000);
            // Send
            socket.send(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is how I call it in my main activity:

```
new UDPTestClient().execute();
```

I am not getting any error messages or exceptions thrown. I think it is an issue with what address I use but I have tried many things, my ip address, localhost, different ports, but no luck. 
On Debugging, the code gets all the way through to the socket.send(packet) line but just passes over it without sending the message to the server. I assume the packet is getting lost on my phones network and never reaching my PC at all.

This issue is frustrating as I am able to make a TCP connection and I am also able to make calls from my device to a REST api running on my PC. The UDP is the only connection not working. I am not an expert on networking stuff so any pointers to where I could read up on it would help me if a simple solution is not available.

Any help is appreciated. This is my first Stackoverflow question so please bear with me. Thanks in advance!

** UPDATE **

I now am able to send UDP messages from the emulator. The address to use for the emulator is 10.0.2.2 from android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking)
Still need to figure out how to get it to work from my phone which is connected over USB. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I dont think there is a need to enable UDP broadcast option since your goal is sending the packet to your PC only. And after reading the DatagramPacket() documentation, addr is the location where you wanted to send the packet and if your client is running on android it should definitely not be localhost, it should be your pc IP. By the way are you push the data through USB or Wi-Fi ?

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure about that broadcast part. I was just able to send the connection from the emulator using the address 10.0.2.2 from the android documentation but still can't from my device. I have my phone connected over USB ideally it would go through wifi though I think. Right now I just need to get the data from the phone to my pc any possible way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try commenting that broadcast line. Pls be more specific what does 10.2.2.2 mean ? State your device IP's and subnets there are in. No! from where it goes depends on the destination address you entered. If the you entered your PC's usb interface address then it would go through USB. If WiFi cards then it would go through Wi-Fi

Comment: Yeah that broadcast line was useless. The 10.0.2.2 is from the android docs [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking). For networking from the emulator you use that address, but it is just for the emulator not for an actual device. I need to read up more on Ip's and addresses and such. know any good recources?

Comment: So is it working now ? regarding material, for starters you can use Wikipedia, But i personally believe References are more complete if you are in long run then consider reading them. Kurose and Ross would be a good one. And for more specific details RFC's are the best

Comment: It is working from the android emulator but not from my device. I am going to edit my question a bit to fit the new situation and will keep troubleshooting. I will also take a look at the literature I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Did you try sending udp messags from android to PC using any other alternative than your app ? If not pls try it once to make sure this is indeed a problem in your code... One way i can suggest is you can use nc , If you get any nc app for android you can try it... otherwise install termux and nc package as you do with debian systems.